# Use the previous 1st of October of the current date in a query

Tags: postgresql

I currently query data like this:

```
SELECT *
   FROM mytable
  WHERE (start_date, end_date) OVERLAPS ('2023-10-01'::DATE, CURRENT_DATE);
```

The problem is that I have to update this query every year. Is there a way to just use the previous 1st of October of the current date in a query?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the last specific month (in your question you need to get the last october) :

```
SELECT (extract(year from current_date) || '-10-01')::date
       - (case when extract(month from current_date) < 10 then 1 else 0 end || ' year')::interval  
AS last_october;
```

For today 2024-01-07 it will results :

```
last_october
2023-10-01 00:00:00+00
```

So your query will be :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (start_date, end_date) OVERLAPS (
                               (extract(year from current_date) || '-10-01')::date
                                - (case when extract(month from current_date) < 10 then 1 else 0 end || ' year')::interval
                                , CURRENT_DATE
                             );
```

`(extract(year from current_date) || '-10-01')::date` retrieves the first of October of the present year. Afterward, subtract one year if the current month is earlier than October, or maintain the current year if the month is October or later.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2RyzbafU)

Comment: But wouldn't I need to update the query every month now and change  "+ interval '9 month'" to 8, 7, 6, ...?

Comment: No, you will not need to change it every month, date_trunc('year', now()) returns first day of the year, and by adding 9 months we get october of the current year

Comment: I have edited my answer and changed the method for obtaining the current year's first October

Answer (score 0):

Subtract `9 months 1 day` from your date: up to October 1st it'll move back to the previous year, or remain in the same year if it's after October 1st. [`Extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) the resulting year, then [`make_date(y,m,d)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.15.6.2.2.29.1.1.1) out of it. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/ld_L0KLU)

```sql
create table mytable (start_date date,end_date date);
insert into mytable values
('2023-01-07','2025-01-07'),
('2021-01-07','2022-01-07');

SELECT *  FROM mytable
WHERE    (start_date,end_date) 
OVERLAPS (make_date(extract(year from CURRENT_DATE-'9 months 1d'::interval)::int,10,1), 
          CURRENT_DATE);
```

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-07 | 2025-01-07 |

If on October 1st you only want to target that one day, as opposed to the whole year since previous October 1st, you can subtract just the `9 months`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you ask (even though not in specific terms) is *given a date what is the beginning of the fiscal year)*. The following is a function I have used for several years for that question (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eTVuAGNF)).

```
create or replace function fiscal_year_start(start_fisyr_in int  default 10
                                            ,from_date_in   date default current_date
                                            )
  returns date 
 language sql
as $$
    with fis_start(mn) as 
         ((select extract(month from from_date_in ) < start_fisyr_in)) 
    select make_date(( extract(year from from_date_in )::int) - mn::int, start_fisyr_in, 01)
      from fis_start;
$$;
```

It basically rest on the concept that a boolean (true,false) can be cast an an integer(1,0). Given that you determine the calendar year that begins the Fiscal Year and from there the date.